# Guard not compiling all the SCSS stylesheets

Tags: sass

When you have a wrapper stylesheet that imports other using sass @import, and when using guard to watch for changes, it wont compile the wrapper stylesheet automatically if you are only changing one of the imported files. Example:

```
/* This is viewports.scss, which must compile into viewports.css */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    @import "480.scss";
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    @import "768.scss";
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    @import "1024.scss";
}
```

When modifying for example 480up.scss, it compiles as expected into 480up.css, **but Guard is not importing it into the viewports.css**, seems like is not recognizing the dependency. This use is important when you want to implement responsive in one compiled css, but writing your code in separate scss files.

If you just use the sass command you have the expected behavior, if you use Guard, not.

Is there some workaround for this? Something extra that I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Guard doesn't know anything about dependencies of your file and just provides the base to easily handle events on file system modifications. I see there are two Guard plugins for sass:

- https://github.com/hawx/guard-sass
- https://github.com/guard/guard-compass

I'd choose guard-sass, since it's actively maintained. When I'm reading the docs, I see

```
:smart_partials => true # Causes guard-sass to do dependency resolution and only
                        # recompile the files that need it when you update partials.
                        # If not on, then guard-sass will update all files when a
                        # partial is changed.
                        # default: false
```

So it looks like guard-sass should already handle your case properly.

Comment: guard-sass is archived now